# How to change pagination total value in joomla?

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I want to change the pagination total value in default.php(tmpl file of view) file.

```
echo $this->pagination->total;
```

The above statement display total value 25(limit=6,so total 5 pages).I want change this as 22(want total 4 pages here)

How to implement it.Please help me anyone.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The total is loaded from your database and setup in the model of the component. I don't think that you want to change the total (as there are 25 items in total not 22), I think you want to change the limit.

Try to add `&limit=7` to your URL.